# How to use Gecko driver in Dynamic Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, geckodriver

I am using Selenium to crawl a website using Java and Gecko driver. When I run the project on a local Tomcat v.9 server I am able to get the path of the Gecko driver directly. But what I want is to be able to run the Gecko exe from within the project folder. The image below shows the project hierarchy. I have added the exe in the "resources" folder under "src". How do I get the path of the driver to use it in my code?
[Project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCmwz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty easy. I noticed that Catalina base has a similar directory to where WEB-INF is. So I did the following;

1. `String catalinaBase= System.getProperty("catalina.base");`

   so the output is;

> C:\Users\<user>\EE
> Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1

Which means I would have to keep this **Path** up until the ".metadata" part (excluding it).

2. `catalinaBase = catalinaBase.split(".metadata")[0];`

I then excluded anything after the "EE Workspace" by splitting the Path String.

3. `mainPath = catalinaBase + "\\Crawler\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\geckodriver.exe";`

I concatenated the Path String I got from step no.2 and the rest of the path I know is the same.

4. `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",mainPath);`

Last but not least I set the system property for gecko driver using the final Path String I created on step 3.

**Bear in mind. I am unaware if this is working when you extract the WAR file. For a local Tomcat server it will work.**

> If someone can let me know if this works when a WAR is exported and
> deployed on a real Tomcat server I would appreciate it.